# Cómo extraer el resultado de console.log

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo hacer un botón link con el resultado de console.log()

No puedo extraer el consolé log para un botón

Comment: No puedes obtener datos del console.log, eso es solo para debugear

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio, ademas obtienes tu primera medalla. Por favor revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Puedes describir mejor lo que deseas lograr (ejemplos) y que has podido realizar? Dependiendo del caso se puede obtener lo que deseas usando una funcion 'hook' que capture los datos.

Comment: fijate si te sirven https://stackoverflow.com/a/42651511/1423096 y https://github.com/samsonradu/console-subscriber

Answer (score 2):

**Saludos,**

Por lo que entiendo, lo que buscas es hacer que un botón ejecute una acción con respecto al resultado del `console.log()` mencionado. Lamento decirte que esto no es posible ya que(referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp), esta función únicamente escribe un mensaje(de tipo String, variable...) en la consola y no en otro lugar. Esto, con el propósito de testeo principalmente. Al no saber específicamente que necesitas hacer o tener tu código, lamento no poder proporcionarte una mejor respuesta. Claro está que si editas tu pregunta, podría darte una mejor asesoría.

Quedo atento a tus inquietudes
P.D: Si quieres averiguar un poco más de `console.log`, puedes visitar estos enlaces: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco extraño lo que quieres hacer pero si tu objetivo poder tener o manejar un valor de una impresión en consola mejor podrías hacer una variable e imprimirla de la siguiente manera.

```js
//Creas una variable
let word = 'Tu texto a imprimir en consola'
//La imprimes en consola :D
console.log(word)
```